# Error converting Caliburn.Micro HelloScreens sample from Silverlight to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am working on a app that needs pretty much the same functionality of the HelloScreens sample from Calibrun.Micro.  I got the code transfered over to a WPF app but when I try and run it I keep getting an error in the BootStrapper GetInstance method

**Could not locate any instances of contract WpfApplication.Framework.IShell.**

My configure is

```
 protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new CompositionContainer(
           new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)))
           );

        var batch = new CompositionBatch();

        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
        batch.AddExportedValue(container);

        container.Compose(batch);
    }
```

Not sure if it is something in the IoC or what.  Any help would be great.  Thanks!!!

Comment: ShellViewModel still has `[Export(typeof(IShell))]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out.  I was missing these two lines in the Configure

```
 batch.AddExportedValue<Func<IMessageBox>>(() => _container.GetExportedValue<IMessageBox>());
 batch.AddExportedValue<Func<CustomerViewModel>>(() => _container.GetExportedValue<CustomerViewModel>());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely IoC related. Check the Export attribute as Derek said. And note, if your ShellViewModel is in another assembly you should also override bootstrappers SelectAssemblies() method.